# Rails engine creates circular dependency fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, rails-engines

I have an app with a rails engine i use.  I've stripped them down pretty much to the bone, but i get a fault when I start the engine up with multi-threading enabled.  I faults out with missing constant the model name i'm calling from the controller.  I've reduced it down to just calling the Model.all.pluck(:id).  And still get the fault.  The models are being invoked via an Ajax call to the controller.

The app runs correctly if i refresh the page and continue, never faulting out again, that I can see.

I think it's actually a multi-treading issue, I'm using Rails 4.1, Ruby 2.12 and Puma 2.8.2  and postgress.

This is happening on my development system a macbook.  I will don't see it in the heroku logs when I deploy, but ??

Now somewhat curious. I've made the issue go away, by forcing the app to load each model in the engine, one at a time.  Things seem to run smoothly after that.

Any suggestions on how to dubug this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is directly linked to `config.eager_load` settings of your app. In production it is set to true so you do not have the circular dependency problem, in development it is generally set to false and that's where rails auto loading systems may trigger this kind of error.

I do believe (though I'm not certain) that you can solve this by *not* declaring nested classes and modules in one single line

Instead of

```
class MyModule::MyClass
  ...
end
```

Use

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks,  I use the second method (didn't really know about the first), so that doesn't fix it.  I'm okay with running single threaded in development as long as I know what's going on.  I checked the eager load, and toggling it makes the error come and go

Comment: I'm actually getting just the opposite.  In Rails 4.1, if I switch to production and run it... I get startup errors RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant API::V1::BaseController  but in development they all render just fine... any tips?